# Diferencia entre Firma digital y certificado digital en un pdf

Tags: pdf, firma-digital

Cuando abro un pdf con Adobe, firmado, me gustaría saber qué diferencia hay entre que Adobe le ponga un check verde o un lazo (a veces azul, a veces negro).
Estoy haciendo un programa para añadir firma digital a un pdf, y me sale el lazo. Me pregunto si estoy haciendo una firma correcta o no. Creo que el lazo es certificado digital y el check es firma digital.... ¿o no?

[image: Imagen] En esta imagen podéis ver los iconos a los que me refiero.
Os pongo el código que uso:

```html
Dim pks As IExternalSignature = New X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, "SHA-1") Dim appearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance Dim signature As PdfSignature = New PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1) MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES)
```

Gracias.

Necesito el check verde, y con este código tan sólo me sale el lazo. ¿Alguna ayuda???

Comment: Hola @Magda te comparto este enlace de [adobe](https://acrobat.adobe.com/es/es/sign/capabilities/digital-signatures-faq.html) en donde explican que son las Firmas digitales. En resumen creo que las firmas digitales las hace un usuario y los certificados las piden las empresas para garantizar que la persona que posee el ID digital es quien dice ser.

Comment: firma digital puede ser hasta escaneada, certificado digital es validado por un tercero y es igual de valida que firma fisicamente

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestros comentarios.
El código que uso, me pone el lazo, y necesito el check. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Os pongo parte del código:
`código`
Dim pks As IExternalSignature = New X509Certificate2Signature(certificate, "SHA-1")
        Dim appearance As PdfSignatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance
        Dim signature As PdfSignature = New PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1)
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES)

Comment: Hola @Magda supongo que usas Vb.net ? Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta con el codigo que acabas de poner para que sea mas legible y le sirva a a las futuras personas que lean tu pregunta

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta, pero aún no he recibido ninguna respuesta. 
Necesito el check verde en la firma, no el lazo
¿Sabe alguien cómo se hace?

Comment: Que libreria utilizas para firmar?

Comment: Para firmar utilizo la librería itextsharp @Marc

Answer (score 0):

Ambos concepto son casi iguales y técnicamente son casi lo mismo pero básicamente las firmas pueden ser varias por documento mientras que tan solo puede haber un certificado.

Esto se hace para poder firmar un documento por varias personas y que la última certifique ya no van a haber más cambios (una firma es un cambio).

Por lo tanto si solo firmas una vez, a la vez que firmas, certificas.

Anteriormente (no se exactamente a partir de que versión) no funcionaba así y todos (especialmente los usuarios) nos acostumbramos a solo buscar el check verde en pdfs firmados.

Yo en un proyecto uso el siguiente código (lo he adaptado), también con iTextSharp (4.1.6)

```
...
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(<rutaDelPdfOriginal>);
using (FileStream fout = new FileStream(<rutaDelPdfFirmado>, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, '\0', null, true);
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
    appearance.Reason = <razonFirma>;
    appearance.Contact = <contactoFirma>;
    appearance.Location = <lugarFirma>;
    //Esto es lo que te hace que sea firma o certificado
    if (<esUltimaFirma>)
    {
        appearance.CertificationLevel = 1; //CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED
    }
    else
    {
        appearance.CertificationLevel = 0; //NOT_CERTIFIED
    }
    appearance.SetCrypto(firma.AKE.Key, firma.Chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
    stamper.Close();
    fout.Dispose();
}
reader.Close();
```

para no hacerlo muy largo, las variables no las he declarado y te las pongo entre <>

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración @Marc